# Capture two regular expression from string

Tags: php, regex

I have strings containing this (where the number are integers representing the user id)

```
  @[calbert](3)
  @[username](684684)
```

I figured I need the following to get the username and user id

```
   \((.*?)\)
```

and

```
   \[(.*?)])
```

But is there a way to get both at once?

And PHP returns, is it possible to only get the result without the parenthesis (and brackets in the username case)

```
  Array
    (
[0] => (3)
[1] => 3
     )
```

Comment: Check the PHP function [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and the [`regex` syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through positive lookbehind and lookahead assertion.

```
(?<=\[)[^\]]*(?=])|(?<=\()\d+(?=\))
```

- `(?<=\[)` Asserts that the match must be preceeded by `[` character,
- `[^\]]*` matches any char but not of `]` zero or more times.
- `(?=])` Asserts that the match must be followed by `]` symbol.
- `|` Called logical OR operator used to combine two regexes.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/32)

Comment: How to only get numbers because is the string is @[leesfer](3) (not that), "not that" is a match ??

Answer (score 3):

```
\[([^\]]*)\]|\(([^)]*)\)
```

Try this. You need to use `|` or operator. This provides regex engine to provide alternating capturing group if the first one fails.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/31

```
$re = "/\\[([^\\]]*)\\]|\\(([^)]*)\\)/im";
$str = " @[calbert](3)\n @[username](684684)";
 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Or you can use your own regex. `\((.*?)\)|\[(.*?)\])`